# Matrix Spectral Radius and Induced Matrix Norms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-norms, spectral-radius

Let $A$ be a matrix, and $\rho(A)$ be its spectral radius, $\|A\|_p$ be an [norm induced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Equivalence_of_norms) from vector $p$-norm.

(1) When $\rho(A)=\|A\|_2$ or $\rho(A)=\|A\|_1$, does $\|A\|_1=\|A\|_2$?

(2) If the answer to question (1) is in the negative, does making $A$ normal or Hermitian imply $\|A\|_1=\|A\|_2$?

(3) What is an example of positive matrix $A$ where $\rho(A)<\|A\|_2$ or $\rho(A)<\|A\|_1$

Comment: Could you define specifically the norms you are referring to? For some norms such an example does not exist, while it is obvious that there are norms with many examples.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval: I have completely modified my question.

Comment: It is worth noting that $A$ is normal $\implies \|A\|_2 = \rho(A)$.  The converse does not generally hold.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Exactly. That is why I word question (2) the way it is.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval: Could you please state which norm gives $\rho(A)=\|A\|$ for all matrix?

Comment: @Hansen there is no norm that gives $\rho(A) = \|A\|$ for all matrices.  In particular, $A\mapsto \rho(A)$ fails to be a matrix norm because it is not sub-additive and not sub-multiplicative.

Comment: And also because there exist $A \neq 0$ with $\rho(A) = 0$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: You are right. I was curious what norm Amitai Yuval had in mind when he said "for some norms such an example does not exist".

Comment: @Hansen I was referring to the previous formulation of the question, which was quite different, and in which you asked about *symmetric* matrices. If $A$ is symmetric, it is diagonalizable, and then $\| A\|=rho(A)$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is any operator norm.

Comment: In other words - The reduction of $A\mapsto\rho(A)$ to the space of *symmetric* matrices is a norm. When general matrices are in question, Omnomnomnom is right of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1): No.  Take
$$
A = \pmatrix{-1&1\\1&1}
$$
We find $\|A\|_2 = \rho(A) = \sqrt 2$, but $\|A\|_1 = 2$.

Conversely, take
$$
B = \pmatrix{2&1\\0&1}
$$
We find $\|A\|_1 = \rho(A) = 2$, but $\|A\|_2 = \sqrt{3 + \sqrt5}$.

(2): No, see the above example.

(3): In addition to the above example, take
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&1\\\epsilon&1}
$$
For some small $\epsilon>0$. We have $\|A\|_2 \approx \sqrt{\frac{3 + \sqrt5}{2}}, \|A\|_1 = 2, \rho(A) \approx 1$.

Or, for a more particular example, take
$$
A = \pmatrix{2&2\\1&2}
$$
We have $\rho(A) = 2 + \sqrt 2$, $\|A\|_1 = 4$, and $\|A\|_2 = \sqrt{\frac{13+3 \sqrt{17}}{2}}$